# Style last of type row with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a question. I have a table like the one below

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="unread"><td>Message</td></tr>
        <tr class="unread"><td>Message</td></tr>
        <tr class="unread"><td>Message</td></tr>
        <tr class="read"><td>Message</td></tr>
        <tr class="read"><td>Message</td></tr>
        <tr class="read"><td>Message</td></tr>
        <tr class="read"><td>Message</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to add a `border-bottom` on the **last** `.unread` with `tr.unread:last-of-type` but doesn't seem to work.

I am seeking for a pure CSS solution, as the number of unread/read rows are changed dynamically and have no access to code.

Comment: If you ask my why, I would say because none of CSS pseudo classes looks through a class list to match `.class`, but through the children tree of the parent to match the valid **element**.

Comment: But about a pure CSS solution, I'm afraid that it's not possible to achieve that probably. At least at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps look at it a different way: you could get the same result by putting a *top* border on the first `.read` row:

```
.unread + .read td {border-top: 1px solid red;}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/yDkBn)

Comment: I posted (then deleted) a similar solution, but this use-case was offered as a criticism: http://jsfiddle.net/634mdLg3/2/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Seems like a valid solution to me! I'll only favor my version because it will work in more browsers (by not depending on `:not`).

Comment: @David Thomas: The question is slightly unclear.  If you want the last .unread whereever that is then that criticis, is valid.  If you want the line whenever it changes between read and undead (i.e. last of that "block" of type) then you just need to add a simialr rule for the .read class. (See http://jsfiddle.net/nz7oh2dd/).  In practice I'm guessing the rows are already sorted :)

Comment: The OP wants to style the last `.unread` message, the last `.unread` message isn't where you think it is in that demo. @adam: possibly, but your assumption seems unreasonable, assuming the nature of any average mail/message client.

Comment: The way the question is presented seems to imply that the `.unread` rows always come before the `.read` rows (though it's not known how many of each there will be). If that's not the case, then this solution won't work—though I'd blame the question for not being clear enough.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yeah - I think both yours and this answers are valid *with the qualificiation* that you assume the rows are sorted first (as given in the example).  If you actually want the *very last* such row you will need to either add an extra class server side or use javascript.